# Boolean and Geo Nodes Causing Problems

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, boolean-modifier

As you will see from the screenshot and the blend file I am having difficulty with the 'screw holes' The one on the left is overlaid on original geometry and booleans fine. The one on the right is geo node generated geometry and doesn't work. What have I missed either in the nodes or the model?

[Blend File](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ct8im48v7mxholbghgfis/Boolean-Problem.blend?rlkey=2jbzm5zyog552ky64rld447yp&dl=0)

[image: Boolean Problem on Geo Node Geometry]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.5)*

The *Reflect* node is changing only the X coordinate, and (-X,Y,Z) is not direct. As a consequence, the inside is now the outside. To check that, select *Face Orientation* in *Viewport Overlays*. To solve that, just insert a *Flip Faces* node after the reflection.

[image: GN graph correction]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Can't believe I didn't think of checking my normals :)